# R - fixed effect of panel data analysis and robust standard errors

Tags: r, plm, standard-error, robust

I am working with the panel data through `plm` package in R. And now I am considering a fixed effect model of group (cities), time, and two ways of group and time, respectively. Because I detected heteroskedasticity through the Breusch-Pagan test, I compute robust standard errors.

I read a help `?vcovHC`, but I could not understand fully how to utilize `coeftest`.

My current code is:

```
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

fem_city <- plm (z ~ x+y, data = rawdata, index = c("city","year"), model = "within", effect = "individual")
fem_year <- plm (z ~ x+y, data = rawdata, index = c("city","year"), model = "within", effect = "time")
fem_both <- plm (z ~ x+y, data = rawdata, index = c("city","year"), model = "within", effect = "twoways")

coeftest(fem_city, vcovHC(fem_city, type = 'HC3', cluster = 'group')
coeftest(fem_year, vcovHC(fem_city, type = 'HC3', cluster = 'time')
```

In order to compute the robust standard errors, are codes of `coeftest` appropriate? I am wondering that how to set the `cluster` option for `effect = 'individual` and `effect = 'time'` each.
For example, I set `coeftest` codes:

`cluster = 'group'` in `plm` of fem_city for `effect = 'individual'` in `coeftest`

`cluster = 'time'` in `plm` of fem_year for `effect = 'time'` in `coeftest`

Is this way appropriate?

And, how to compute the robust standard error for twoways of both `city` and `year`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `cluster='group'` if you want to cluster on the variable serving as the individual index (`city` in your example).

Set `cluster='time'` if you want to cluster on the variable serving as the time index (`year`in your example).

You can cluster on the time index even for a fixed effects one-way individual model.

For clustering on both index variables, you cannot do that with `plm::vcovHC`. Look at `vcovDC` from the same packages which provides double clustering (DC = double clustering), e.g.,

`coeftest(fem_city, vcovDC(fem_city)`